# How to run docker containers in host network mode using docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm

I need to run containers from docker-compose in host network mode.
For example, if I run single container, I write:

```
docker run --net=host my_image
```

How to do this part `--net=host` in docker-compose?

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent in docker-comopose is `network_mode: host` see the documentation in: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Answer (score 0):

add directory network_mode of the networks section to your service definition in your docker-compose.yml

also, pay attention network_mode is incompatible with port_bindings:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  server:
    image: custome image
    container_name: "sample"
    command: bash -c "python sample.py"
    
    network_mode: host
```

Comment: not working for swarm. there are is conflicts